# Alternative careers for one who wanted to study theoretical physics

Tags: careers, job-description

I have immense interest in physics and maths and I love thinking and brainstorming.

So naturally, the field "Theoretical Physics" allured me.

But later I came to know that the job opportunity as an actual theoretical physicist is quite slim [(source)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3257/what-is-the-statistical-likelihood-of-getting-a-job-as-a-theoretical-physicist&ved=2ahUKEwj7po7s7YLdAhVKsI8KHbw1Ao0QFjAAegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw35pQUEGmh6dvnQAbWvYWss). I know that you can still work for different companies for helping them with your mathematical and creative brain, but those jobs have almost no relation with pure physics.

So, I have no choice but to stop pursuing this.

So which careers would be best for me now which would give me at least part of the enjoyment that I would've gotten if I were to be an actual researcher i.e. theoretical physicist ?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm in high school

Comment: Many analyst have degrees in physics.  From finance, to business, to engineering.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere ummm..... that's the problem, I have none

Comment: I have to agree with Joe, @AbuSafwanMdfarhan career advice is something that can't be answered here, it would be best you checked with someone you trust (some teacher, even better if related to physics) or with your school counselor.

Comment: @DarkCygnus would it be appropriate for Academia SE?

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan I doubt that they give career advice there, the SE network is not so fond of opinion based answers... also there are many advantages in asking someone of trust, rather than kind strangers on the internet

Comment: Even if jobs for theoretical physicists are rare, just remember - you only need one of them.

Comment: @DanPichelman ummmm...., yeah , but, will I be able? That's a jump to uncertainty.

Comment: Life is uncertain.  The best you can hope to do is follow your passion and see where it leads.

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan in physics, as well as in life, one has do deal with uncertainty all the time my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most well known theoretical physicists worked in the patent office to support his seminal research.

But if that is not how you envision your future, there are lots of careers in applied physics which provide plenty of challenges. Space and aeronautics, nuclear and alternative power, bioinformatics are some example industries where solid math and physics skills are needed.

These industries, along with the digital entertainment field and research institutions like CERN also need physics simulation specialists.

Start with a solid college education with math, physics and computer science, and you are bound to find something that interests you.